# Building a jsonb object without using subquery in postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called users that has a jsonb column called 'history'. This is an array of objects, one of the elements is called uid which is the id of the person visiting the page as follows:

`[ {"ip":"...","uid":2} , {"ip":"...","uid":4} , ... ]`

I'm running a query that appends the jsonb object with the field `uname` to make understanding who 'uid' is a bit easier which will produce:

`[ {"ip":"...","uid":2,"uname":"bob"} , {"ip":"...","uid":4,"uname":"dave"} , ... ]`

I'm currently doing this using the following query (say, where uid=2):

```
SELECT json_agg(history2||jsonb_build_object('uname',uname::text)) FROM 
  (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(history) AS history2 FROM users WHERE uid=2) AS table1 
  LEFT JOIN users AS table2 ON history2->>'uid'=table2.uid
```

I'm using the subquery to return a table of json objects that's then joined to the user table again to get the username.

My question is: Is there a way of doing this without having the subquery?  I've read that lateral joins could be used but all my attempts at this don't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the subquery (which is actually a derived table). If you need to change every element of an array, then the only choice you have is to unnest the array, change each element and aggregate back - exactly what you are doing. And this shows once again why JSON isn't always a good idea. In a a properly normalized model this wouldn't be necessary to begin with

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I agree there's nothing wrong with the subquery. This is more for my own personal learning about JSON processing in postgres rather than a specific application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `jsonb_array_elements` into the FROM clause with an outer join:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(h.item||jsonb_build_object('uname', u.uname)) 
FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements(u.history) as h(item) on h.item ->> 'uid' = u.uid::text
WHERE u.uid = 2
```